# Is using storyboard for iOS 7 dev mandatory?

Tags: ios, ios7

I don't know if this question fits here or not. My apologies if it doesn't.

I am developing an iOS 7 app and have used XIBs instead of storyboard.

Can this be any reason for app rejection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it can not be a reason for rejection. 
You a free to use either storyboard or xib or even declare all your UI in code like Telegram messenger does.

Check [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) to see possible reasons for rejection.

Comment: Indeed; we've an app that was initially started under iOS 4 and have never been able to justify the development budget for throwing the current structure away and storyboarding. We've long ago stopped supporting anything other than 7 owing to our testing footprint and our use of other more recent innovations. Apple hasn't raised any concerns.